# Lora Sensor (Elsys ERS) to Lora antenna (Multitech Antenna)

Tags: iot, sensors, lora, lorawan

I am using Lora technology to send Data from a Lora sensor (Elsys ERS: [link](https://www.elsys.se/en/ers/)) to a Lora Base station (multitech MultiConnect Conduit IP67 Base Station: [link](http://www.multitech.net/developer/products/multiconnect-conduit-platform/basestation/)). I have configured the sensor using an android application (using NFC) as in the manual. For the configuration, I followed the manual ([link](https://www.multitech.com/documents/publications/manuals/S000665.pdf)) of the base station and a youtube tuto ([link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q_25lZWcSWI&t=850s)), but I still do not know how it works.

Now I want to know how to receive a data from this sensor using the cited base station.

PS: the multitech bas station is equipped with a lora antenna.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to update the software version, called Application Execution Platform (or AEP). Then, you have to "Save and Restart" the system. After that, you can add all the nodes you need by only using the AEP.
It is recommended to "Save and Restart" each time you do a modification on the system. Elsewhere, the modifications risk not to be considered by the system.

For more information, please visit the YouTube channel of Multitech: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6-Nw7I6yCuY&t=296s

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your MultiTech gateway is running the latest firmware, 1.6.4 as of this writing.

[image: screenshot lora gateway]

You will have a bunch of LoRa settings, you will be able to see uplink packets and send downlink packets too.

Most important configuration parameters are:
 * DevEUI (like a MAC address of the device).
 * Frequency sub-band (your gateway can only do one sub-band, your sensor needs to use the same one; more expensive gateways can do 2 or more sub-bands).
 * AppEUI (like a group of devices, the sensor will connect to it)
 * AppKey (Encryption key)

If those 4 things are match then your device should be able to connect.